# Using TFS Client Object Model to get who has currently checked out a file

Tags: tfs, locks, vcs-checkout

I am using the 2012 edition of the TFS Client Object Model to retrieve some file information within repositories. Given a string specifying the path to a file in a TFS project, I'd like to find out who has checked out a file if it is locked. I use `VersionControlServer.GetItems(...).Items` and a `Where` predicate to get only the files (not folders) I am interested in.

Comment: I find that it's easier to just have a look in Visual Studio and TFS to see who has a file checked out or locked. Have you tried looking at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138911.aspx (all the other GetItems(...) found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.getitems.aspx)

Comment: I need to do it programmatically. Its for a project, not just for my own code management. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QueryPendingSets` is your friend!

**Sample**:

```
PendingSet[] queryPendingSets = versionControlServer.QueryPendingSets(new [] {"$/A/B/C.txt"},RecursionType.None, null, null );
```

This lists all pending changes for the specified file.
You can get them all by looking at:

```
queryPendingSets[0].PendingChanges
```

Comment: Thats it! `queryPendingSets[0].OwnerName` is precisely what I wanted. :)